# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'

Tags: json

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Почему браузер говорит, что неожиданное двоеточие? Валидатор JSON это проходит положительно

```
{
    "id": 0,
    "name_test": "Окрашиваете ли вы волосы?",
    "variants": [
        {
            "variant_name": "Да",
            "variant_text": "Вы регулярно окрашиваете волосы стойкой, краской тон в тон или делаете мелирование.",
            "next_id": null
        },
        {
            "variant_name": "Нет",
            "variant_text": "Вы не красили волосы более года.",
            "next_id": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Возможно, браузер считает, что это JavaScript-файл, а не JSON.

Comment: этот файл как-то подключается на страницу?

Comment: @Grundy ой да, я подключаю в теге script. Я хотел локально создать JSON файл и его редактировать, чтобы потом с этим можно на бэке работать. Мне пришло в голову только просто создать js файл с переменной в виде JSON

Comment: в теге скрипт по умолчанию может быть только js код. Именно поэтому твой json подсвечивается, так как не является валидным яваскрипт кодом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Моя ошибка была в том, что я подключал свой JSON файл в теге `script`:
`<script src="information.json"></script>`
Мой вопрос решило:
1) Я обращаюсь к серверу POST-запросом, получаю этот JSON
2) Готово